# Geocoder IntentService is not being called

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, google-geocoder

I understand this questions has been asked many times, for each question that has already been asked, the implementation is different from mine.  The method I used create and call the intentService for a geocoder, was used from the android dev tutorial site.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html. 
 I have gone over the the tutorial 3 times over to make sure I wasn't missing anything, but it is clear that I am.

Here is my manifest file, I have added the location and internet permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".selectRouteAndTransportMethod">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    <service
        android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    </activity>
    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="user.com.commuterapp.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
 App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Here is my main activity:  All I am doing here is using a buttonClick to create the intent and to start the intent.

```
package user.com.commuterapp;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;


import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import user.com.commuterapp.R;

import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;

public class selectRouteAndTransportMethod extends AppCompatActivity {

Intent mIntent;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
myLocation mCurrentLocation;
private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
public static final String TAG = selectRouteAndTransportMethod.class.getSimpleName();
/**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_route_and_transport_method);

    mIntent = new Intent(this, selectRouteAndTransportMethod.class);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mIntent, 0);
    mCurrentLocation = new myLocation(this, this, mPendingIntent);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.

    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.



}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Log.d(TAG, "On Start");

    mCurrentLocation.connect();

    boolean connecting = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting();
    boolean registered = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.isConnectionCallbacksRegistered(mCurrentLocation);
        //ConnectionResult connectionResult = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.getConnectionResult(LocationServices.API);

    if (connecting == TRUE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connecting");
        }

    if (registered == TRUE) {
        Log.d(TAG, "registered");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mCurrentLocation.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
 //   mCurrentLocation.disconnect();
}

protected void buttonOriginClick(View view)
{
    Log.d(TAG,"retrieving address");
    retrieveAddress();
}

protected void retrieveAddress() {
   Intent geoCoderIntent = new Intent(this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);
   geoCoderIntent.putExtra(FetchAddressIntentService.Constants.RECIEVER, mResultReceiver);
   geoCoderIntent.putExtra(FetchAddressIntentService.Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mCurrentLocation.mCurrentLocation);
   startService(geoCoderIntent);
}
}
```

And lastly here is the intentService class.  This was straight out of the android dev tutorial site, nothing original here.

```
    package user.com.commuterapp;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

/**
 * Created by User on 1/21/2017.
 */

public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {

    public final class Constants{
        public static final int SUCCESS_RESULT = 0;
        public static final int FAILURE_RESULT = 1;
        public static final String PACKAGE_NAME =
                "user.com.commuterapp";
        public static final String RECIEVER = PACKAGE_NAME +
                ".RECIEVER";
        public static final String RESULT_DATA_KEY = PACKAGE_NAME + ".RESULT_DATA_KEY";
        public static final String LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA = PACKAGE_NAME +
                ".LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA";
    }

    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;

    public FetchAddressIntentService()
    {
        super("FetchAddressIntentService");
    }

    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);
        mReceiver.send(resultCode,bundle);
    }

    @Override
    protected  void onHandleIntent (Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "GeoCoder Service Started");


        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String errorMessage = "";

        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);

        List<Address> addresses = null;

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                    location.getLongitude(),
                    location.getLatitude(),
                    1);
        }catch (IOException ioException) {
                //catch network or other I/O Problems
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException){
                //catch invalid latitude or longitude values
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + "." + "Latitude =" + location.getLatitude()
                        + ", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude(),
                        illegalArgumentException);


        }
        //handle cases where no addresses was foudn
        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0)
        {

           if(errorMessage.isEmpty()){
               errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
               Log.e(TAG,errorMessage);
           }
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
        }else
        {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine
            //join them and send them to the thread

            for(int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
            }

            Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.address_found));
            deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                    TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.seperator"), addressFragments));
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: I have tried rewriting the geocoder following the instructions from the android dev site again, but no success.

EDIT2:  I noticed in the manifest I declared the service, within the application declaration, instead of outside, I made the change but to no avail, any insights will be appreciated

Comment: I resolved the problem and I am posting the solution in case someone else has the same problem as I do.  Originally, I created the AddressResultReciever class in a separate file, but all the geocoder examples showed that the class should be in the main activity, doing so resolved the problem.